# AMP version of front page without plugin

Tags: templates, frontpage, endpoints

The below code is working for all pages and posts but it is not working for front page anybody helps me.

e.g HTML version `www.example.com` and AMP version `www.example.com/amp`

How to include amp template for the front page?

```
<?php
    define( 'AMP_QUERY_VAR', apply_filters( 'amp_query_var', 'amp' ) );

    add_rewrite_endpoint( AMP_QUERY_VAR, EP_PERMALINK );

    add_filter( 'template_include', 'amp_page_template', 99 );

    function amp_page_template( $template ) {

        if( get_query_var( AMP_QUERY_VAR, false ) !== false ) {


            if ( is_single() ) {

                $template = get_template_directory() .  '/amp-single.php';

            } 

        }

        return $template;
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`is_single()` will return false for Pages, so the above code as written *should* only work for single Posts.

You'll need to add more conditionals to your `amp_page_template()` function for each of the templates you want to replace with an AMP version. Depending on your settings in Settings > Reading > Front page displays, [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) might be what you're looking for, alternatively you could try [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/).